# Batch counter program shutting down

Tags: batch-file

So I am making a counter and I am not sure how to make it work.. I have this right now with some other functions for customization purposes:

```
set /a current_value=current_value+incremental_value
```

but it does not work unfortunately..
The whole purpose is to use the pause `>nul` function so when ever the user presses a key then the screen will show a number go up by the incremental value chosen earlier..

This is the whole script:

```
@echo off
cls
title Counter

:Incremental_Value
cls
echo./----------------------------------------------\
echo.I  Set the Incremental Value then press Enter  I
echo.\----------------------------------------------/
echo.
set /p %incremental_value%= [

:Starter_Value
cls
set current_value=%starter_value%
echo./------------------------------------------\
echo.I  Set the Starter Value then press Enter  I
echo.\------------------------------------------/
echo.
set /p %starter_value%= [
goto Counter

:Counter
cls
echo./-------------------\
echo.I        %current_value%        I
echo.\-------------------/
echo.
pause >nul
set /a current_value=current_value+incremental_value
goto Counter
```

Edit: I fixed the shutting down problem, but when you first get to the Counter screen the number does not appear. Once you hit a key it becomes zero (if you set the starting value to zero) then it wont add the incremental value if you continue to press the key.

Comment: Can you post the script? There is not allot to work with here. I would suggest try putting the set within quotes, ex: `set /a "current_value=current_value+incrimental_value"`

Comment: It still shut down after that I will go ahead and put in the script

Comment: I bet that command works OK (despite ii could be shorter : `set /a current_value+=incremental_value`), most likely you are trying to **use** that new value in a code block without using delayed expansion. So show more of the context to prove this.

Comment: I also tried your shorter method and It did the same thing I explained in the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple issue you had was the improper use of the `set /p` command. When using `set /p`, you do not specify the string as `set /p %String%=` but rather `set /p String=`. For more information on the set command try typing `set /?` into a command prompt.

Another issue, not problem is that you have `:Incremental_Value` & `:Starter_Value` but you never c`all` or `goto` them in the script. The only place you properly did this was with `goto Counter`. Unless you are going to individually `goto`/`call` them later, just remove them; or use `goto :Starter_Value` - exc.

In the future, try using `echo(` instead of `echo.` to call a blank space in the window.

**Counter.bat**

```
@echo off
title Counter With Incremental Progression

echo ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»
echo º  Set the Starter Value then press Enter  º
echo ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼
echo(
set /p starter_value=Value: 

cls
echo ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»
echo º  Set the Incremental Value then press Enter  º
echo ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼
echo(
set /p incremental_value=Value: 

Set "current_value=%starter_value%"

:Counter
cls
echo Current Number: %current_value%
echo(
pause >nul
set /a "current_value=current_value+incremental_value"
goto Counter
```

**PS:** Switch the file encoding to `ANSI` for fun boxes - `:-)`

Comment: Please note that you have to quote the whole variable set in `set /a`. Also, please note that there are `+=`, `-=`, e.t.c. operators in batch file. Please check `set /?`.

Comment: @double-beep You just repeated what I original told the OP. I got lazy I will admit and did not do it on my script - However, for integers it is not needed and is perfectly fine. For the `+=` operator, my alternative is perfectly fine and has an equal impact to the scripts functionality. However, to appease you I went ahead and quoted my `set` command. Thanks for the point out.

Comment: Well, I know... This has happened to me also.